# Python add a method to print the content of an object (in a tree structure)

Tags: python, oop, binary-tree

This is a problem which I have to solve. I have spent a few hours trying to solve this but haven't been able to. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Question

Implement a method ls() that recursively prints the content of the directory
and all the subdirectories, using indentation to represent how deep
in the tree structure the file/directory is.

## if we run ls() on the previous object root, It should display:

```
>> root.ls()
root
 boot.exe
 home
  thor
   hunde.jpg
   quatsch.txt
isaac
   gatos.jpg
```

My code so far

```
class File:
    
    owner="default"

class Directory (File):
    
    
    def __init__(self,name,right):
        self.name=name
        self.right=right
    
    def chown (self,new_owner):
        self.new_owner=new_owner
        File.owner=new_owner
        
  
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "Directory({},{})".format(self.name,self.right)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Directory({},{})".format(self.name,self.right)

#Method ls() which recursively prints the content of the directory and all the subdirectories


class PlainFile(File):
    
    
    def __init__(self,filename):
        self.filename=filename
    
    def chown (self,new_owner):
        self.new_owner=new_owner
        File.owner=new_owner
        
   
    def __str__ (self):
        return "PlainFile ({})".format (self.filename)
    
    
    def __repr__ (self):
        return "PlainFile ({})".format (self.filename)

    
print("Testing question 1")

# question 1 should allow to create simple files and folders:
file = PlainFile("boot.exe")
folder = Directory("Downloads",[])
    
root = Directory("root",[PlainFile("boot.exe"),
               Directory("home",[
                   Directory("thor",
                      [PlainFile("hunde.jpg"),
                       PlainFile("quatsch.txt")]),
                   Directory("isaac",
                      [PlainFile("gatos.jpg")])])])

print("-------------------------------------------------------------------------- \n")

#This is to test Question 2 
print(root)

print("-------------------------------------------------------------------------- \n")

#This is to test Question 3
file = PlainFile("boot.exe")
folder = Directory("Downloads",[])
print(f'file.owner: {file.owner}; folder: {folder.owner}')
file.chown("root")
folder.chown("isaac")
print(f'file.owner: {file.owner}; folder: {folder.owner}')

print("-------------------------------------------------------------------------- \n")
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your function should pass itself an indentation (string) that it increases at each recursion call:

```
def ls(node,indent=""):
    print(indent + node.name)       # print indented name
    if isinstance(node,Directory):  # for directories
       for subNode in node.right:   # recursive calls for each item
           ls(subNode,indent+"  ")  # with increased indentation
```

If you make this a method of the File/Directory classes, you can use `self` instead of `node` for the 1st parameter and specialize the Directory class to make it print its subnodes:

```
# in the File class
def ls(self,indent=""):
    print(indent + self.name)    # print indented name

# in the Directory class
def ls(self,indent=""):
    super().ls(indent)           # from base class
    for subNode in self.right:   # recursive calls for each item
        subNode.ls(indent+"  ")  # with increased indentation
```

*note that your base class (File) should set the owner as an instance member (in its `__init__()` method) and subclasses should call the base class' `__init__()` method from super().  This will allow each file/directory to have a specific owner.  With the code as it is, there will only be one owner common to all Files because the File.owner is a class variable*

Comment: Thank you so much for helping us out.